# .NET Performance Counters Getting Corrupted, How do I find out why/how?

Tags: .net, performancecounter

So here's the situation.  At my work place this morning 7 of our servers suddenly were choking on places using custom .NET PerformanceCounters (they had been working fine for months).  In particular, even though the counters were single-instance counters, .NET thought they were multi-instance counters and threw an exception for the first time today.

No new code rolled out, but system admin rolled out several patches throughout the week and then rebooted them this weekend (that's when the problem started occurring).  They also don't have a lot of available information on what they installed and if it touched the registry (not sure if they don't know or can't say for some system security reason).

I can rebuild the counters easily enough (using "lodctr /r" to repair or "installutil" to uninstall/reinstall the counters) and it works again, so my question isn't how to fix this.

My question is that I'm wondering if there's any way I can analyze the corrupted machines (I have them for a few hours before they will be fixed after market hours, no changes allowed till then) to see how they got corrupted to see what the offending modification was?

I know there are perf*.dat files in windows/system32 and of course the big registry keys in local machine/software/Microsoft/WindowsNt/CurrentVersion/Perflib/9, I've peeked at these, but not sure how a corruption in these could result in it thinking the isntance type of the category was completely different...

If it helps, the following were the installed patches:

KB975558
KB2544893
KB2536276
KB2535512
KB2503665
KB2476490
KB2443105
KB2440591
KB2436673
KB978542
KB2423089
KB2416451
KB2387149
KB237811
KB2360937
KB2347290
KB2296199
KB979687
KB2124261
KB2229593
KB2296011
KB2286198
KB980436
KB981322
KB2259922
KB982132
KB982214
KB2121546
KB2115168

Comment: *either they don't know or won't admit* ...well, they won't admit they don't know - ever. But it seems obvious that one of the patches caused something to go awry.

Comment: I agree, but I'd love to be able to warn the other groups when the offending patch/install happens that they should rebuild their counters afterwards.

Comment: Warnings would be nice - definitely.